# SQL Server and Oracle compatible multi-row insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

I'm looking for a multiple row insert query that is compatible with Oracle 11g and SQL Server 2008 versions forward.

We have to support both databases and generate scripts that will work on both. We have some sections of scripts split for specific things on each database, but there are large common INSERT INTO statements that run one at a time.

One way to increase performance would be to take these thousands of insert into statements and bundle them into multi-row inserts. Is there no way to do this without splitting up these common script section files into separate files again? We'd like to avoid this if possible to avoid having to update data in two files when making changes.

Most SO results I saw dealt with performing multi-row inserts for Oracle OR SQL Server, but none of the answers I've seen are compatible in both when inserting NEW values.

I've also looked at this wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)

And tried some tests with scripts below.

```
create table test (
    testCol1 varchar(32),
    testCol2 varchar(32),
    CONSTRAINT PK_TEST PRIMARY KEY (testCol1)
);

--compatible with sql server, but not oracle
insert into test (testCol1, testCol2) values
    ('hi', 'test'),
    ('again', 'test');

--works in Oracle, but not SQL Server
INSERT ALL
    INTO test values ('hi', 'test')
    INTO test values ('again', 'test')
SELECT * FROM DUAL

--works in SQL Server, but not Oracle
INSERT INTO test
SELECT 'hi', 'test'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'again','test'

--works in Oracle, but not SQL Server
INSERT INTO test
SELECT 'hi', 'test' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'again','test' FROM DUAL

--"standard-conforming" but works in neither?
INSERT INTO test ("testCol1", "testCol2")
SELECT 'hi', 'test' FROM LATERAL ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(c)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'again','test' FROM LATERAL ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(c)
```

Any advice or anything that I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that it makes sense to architect this as insert statements in the first place (particularly if performance is a concern)?  Both SQL Server and Oracle (and realistically any other database) can ingest a file of data into a table with a few lines of code very quickly.  I'd much rather have a dozen lines of database-specific code to load the data and have a flat file with 27,000 rows of data I could open in Excel/ my favorite text editor than a database agnostic script with 27,000 separate insert statements.  The flat file would also load much faster.

Comment: That is a good suggestion, but part of the reason why we do it this way is that we deliver these scripts to the customers as well as the code. They have the ability to look through the script and modify it as needed. I'll keep this in mind though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

If you need code that works in both SQL Server and Oracle, then define a `dual` table:

```
create table dual (dummy int);

insert into dual (dummy) (1);
```

Then you will be able to use the method that uses `union all` and `from dual`.

You are explicitly asking about multi-row inserts.  Obviously an alternative is a separate `insert` statement for each row.

Comment: We already use thousands of insert into statements. I'm trying to figure out a good way to refactor this to reduce file size and make it easier to modify and add values.

An example is that one of our files is 27,000 lines long insert into (every, column, listed, here) statements where the values themselves can be a couple text values, then 20 integers or null values. This is just bloating the file itself up significantly.

I've also read that many single row insert into statements is much less efficient than a bulk insert so we can speed up our continuous integration.

Comment: Also, it appears that what you've suggested just doesn't work.


If I've messed up somewhere please explain:


create table test (
 testCol1 varchar(32),
 testCol2 varchar(32),
 CONSTRAINT PK_TEST PRIMARY KEY (testCol1)
);


create table dual (
 testCol1 varchar(32),
 testCol2 varchar(32)
);


INSERT INTO test
SELECT 'hi', 'test' FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'again','test' FROM dual


This doesn't insert any records.

Comment: @EddieHartman [SQL Server db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d72e8c8ff367d2367ba5a2a85ad09152) with same statement as [Oracle db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d1ca0a4c08e2d24bc8e064082b50062a)

Comment: @MT0 Thank you. I hadn't inserted any values into the dual table, so it would insert 0 values. Looking up "sql dummy" (what a great google search) and the dual table explained what that means. Thank you both.